# Android ListView Async

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have a list that when I click on an item another screen should appear. I've successfully done this before but I've moved my list to Async - so the class extends AsyncTask not ListView. 
I'm assuming this is why I'm getting errors on the following methods:

```
getListView();
getApplicationContext();
startActivity(in);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have presented no code, how should someone help you?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need both a `List` and an `AsyncTask`. Use `onProgressUpdate` or `onPostExecute` to update your list from your `AsyncTask`.